# python remove characters between quotes

Tags: python, string, substring

I tried to remove characters between quotes.

Input string: "a string ,5,to",5,6,my,use,"123456,inside",1,a,b

I would like this output: 5,6,my,use,1,a,b

I tried with re.sub without success:

```
line = ['"a string ,5,to",5,6,my,use,"123456,inside",1,a,b']
substr = re.sub("[\"\].*?[\"\]", "", line)
```

many thanks for any help

Comment: Remove the brackets around the content of `line`.
`re.sub` expects a string, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match two double-quotes with zero or more non-double-quote characters in between, and substitute the match with an empty string. Also match an optional comma that follows to remove it:

```
import re

line = '"a string ,5,to",5,6,my,use,"123456,inside",1,a,b'
print(re.sub(r'"[^"]*",?', '', line))
```

This outputs:

```
5,6,my,use,1,a,b
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ConsiderableDapperBrain

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
import re

input_string = '"a string ,5,to",5,6,my,use,"123456,inside",1,a,b'
output_list = re.findall(r'"[^"]*?"|\w+', input_string)
output_string = ','.join([word for word in output_list if not 
word.startswith('"')])

print(output_string)
```

my output:

```
5,6,my,use,1,a,b
```